# Convert type from a different directory

Tags: go, casting, type-conversion

Current structure of project is like this:

```
project 
---main.go
---src
------file.go
```

Inside `file.go` I created a variable:

```
f := &FileInfo{}
```

Then I stored this variable in the `map[string]interface{}`. 
When I want to get back that variable:

```
ff, ok := mymap[filename].(*FileInfo)
```

I have a problem because `ok` is `false`. The debugger tells me that actual type is `*src.FileInfo`. So I tryed:

```
ff, ok := mymap[filename].(*src.FileInfo)
```

It gives me another error:

```
src is undefined
```

So how I should correctly get that value from the map?

Comment: Have you tested that you'd imported `src` correctly?

Comment: Can you post the complete source files, including the imports?

Comment: You are missing the package decl. here: f := &FileInfo{} - it seems to me that you have used a type definition somewhere in src?